# Números e seus amigos

Tags: code-golf

A soma de todo o número natural (inteiro positivo) de divisores 220, exceto 220, é igual a:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 + 11 + 20 + 22 + 44 + 55 + 110 = 284
```

E a soma de todo o número natural de divisores 284, exceto ele próprio, é igual a:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + 71 + 142 = 220
```

Os números 220 e 284 são chamados de *friends*. Geralmente, dizemos que dois inteiros positivos são *friends* se cada uma das soma de seus divisores (excluindo o próprio número) é igual o outro número.

#### Escreva o programa para calcular todos os números *friends* de 2 para N.

Exemplo:

Se a entrada for `N = 1500` a saída deverá ser: `(284, 220)`, `(1210, 1184)`

Obs: Use a linguagem que preferir.

Comment: Quem está negativando, por favor, leia aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366/desafios-e-code-golf

Comment: De forma geral, você vai precisar de uma função que retorne uma lista dos divisores de um determinado número, outra que retorne a soma dos valores de uma lista, e para cada número de 2 até N, ele vai pegar a lista de divisores, somar para obter um "candidato a friend", depois pegar a lista de divisores do candidato e somar para comparar com o original.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK sim, mas você sabe o que é Code Golf? O desafio é escrever um programa que gere este resultado com o menor número de caracteres possível.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Python (115 bytes)

```py
N,d=1500,lambda n:sum(i for i in range(1,n) if n%i==0)
print({i:d(i) for i in range(N+1) if i==d(d(i)) and i>d(i)})
```

Saída:

```
{284: 220, 1210: 1184}
```

**Explicação:**

Na primeira linha é definido os valores de `N`, 1500, e `d`, uma função *lambda* que calcula a soma dos divisores de um valor `n`. Por sua vez, na segunda linha é utilizado a sintaxe de *dict comprehension*, retornando o par `i: d(i)` para todo valor de `i` que seja igual à `d(d(i))` e que seja maior que `d(i)`, no intervalo definido por `range(2,N+1)`. A própria condição `i>d(i)` já elimina os pares duplicados, tais como `(284, 220)` e `(220, 284)` e pares compostos por números perfeitos, tais como `(6, 6)` e `(28, 28)`, que satisfazem a condição `i == d(d(i))`.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/iHBVwE).

Answer (score 17):

## JavaScript ES6 (153 bytes)

```js
N=1500,d=n=>[...Array(n).keys()].reduce((s,i)=>n%i==0?s+i:s,0);alert([...Array(N+1).keys()].reduce((v,i)=>i==d(d(i))&&i>d(i)?v.concat([[i,d(i)]]):v,[]));
```

Saída:

```
284,220,1210,1184
```

**Explicação:**

Basicamente a mesma ideia da [implementação em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/223946/5878): inicia a variável `N` com o valor desejado, define `d` como uma *arrow function* que calcula a soma de todos os divisores de `n`, após percorre toda a lista de `N` valores reduzindo-a à uma lista com os números amigos. Utiliza-se aqui `[...Array(n).keys()]` para gerar uma lista de inteiros entre 0 e `n`: `[0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n-1]`.

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Jhpz/3).

Answer (score 17):

#### C# (*LINQ way*) 284 bytes

> **Disclaimer**: Só vai funcionar em consoles interativos, como **LINQPad** ou **C# Interactive** do Visual Studio, porque não foi definida uma classe pública para o método `Main()`

```cs
static int d(int n) => Enumerable.Range(1, n-1).Where(i => n % i == 0).Sum();   
void Main()
{
    int N = 1500;       
    var q = from e in Enumerable.Range(2, N-1)
            let k = d(d(e))
            let v = d(e)
            where e == k && e > v
            select new {k,v};

    foreach(var a in q) Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

<sup>[Código no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/tree/master/CSharp/223924)</sup>

Saída (forma padrão para objetos anônimos):

> { v = 284, x = 220 }
>   { v = 1210, x = 1184 }

Explicação:

Define a variável `N` com o valor desejado (1500), `d` como um método (*expression bodied function*) que calcula a soma de todos os divisores de `n`, excluindo ele próprio. A *query* LINQ percorre toda a lista de N valores reduzindo a mesma a uma lista de objetos anônimos com os números amigos.

Answer (score 16):

#### Kotlin (151 bytes)

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>){val n=1500;print((2..n).filter{i->d(d(i))==i&&i>d(i)}.map{"${it}-${d(it)}"})}fun d(n: Int)=(1..n-1).filter{n%it==0}.sum()
```

Versão legível

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val n = 1500
    print((2..n)
          .filter{i -> d(d(i)) == i && i > d(i) }
          .map{"${ it }-${ d(it) }"})
}    

fun d(n: Int) = (1..n-1).filter { n % it == 0 }.sum()
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no try.kotlin**](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/hc1br45o7ceolvlhfpb47cresj/hnq7s91ltsb2kk4cbdrme4noea) **|** [Código no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/jfbueno/Stack-Overflow-Portugues/tree/master/Kotlin/223924)</sup>

Saída:

> [284-220, 1210-1184]

A implementação é [exatamente a mesma do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224225/18246) (e também das respostas do Anderson).

Answer (score 15):

## C# (míseros 5.120 bytes)

> Muitos Bytes! Mas o que importa é que está funcionando! hahaha

Código:

```cs
using System;class Program{static void Main(string[] args){int N = 1500; for (int n = 2; n < N; n++){double valor1 = somar(somar(n)); double valor2 = somar(n); if (n == valor1 && n != valor2)Console.WriteLine(valor1 + ", " + valor2);}}static double somar(double n, int sum = 0){for (int N = 1; N < n; N++)if ((n / N) % 1 == 0)sum += N; return sum;}}
```

Código legível:

```cs
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N = 1500;
        for (int n = 2; n < N; n++)
        {
            double valor1 = somar(somar(n)); double valor2 = somar(n);
            if (n == valor1 && n != valor2)
                Console.WriteLine(valor1 + ", " + valor2);
        }
    }
    static double somar(double n, int sum = 0)
    {
        for (int N = 1; N < n; N++)
            if ((n / N) % 1 == 0)
                sum += N; return sum;
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
220, 284
1184, 1210
```

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (<s>108</s> <s>105</s> <s>102</s> 101 bytes)

```js
N=1500,x={},r=[];for(i=1;N-++i;){s=0;for(j=i;--j;)x[i]=s+=i%j?0:j;x[s]==i&s!=i?r.push(i,s):0}alert(r)
```

Esta versão usa um dicionário de suporte para manter os números e as respetivas somas de divisores, e consequentemente verificar se existe *friend* para o numero corrente.

É uma solução um pouco mais à mão, não utilizando funções como `reduce`, `map`, `filter`, etc.

Versão legivel:

```js
let N = 1500;
let numeros = {};
let res = [];

for(let i = 2;i <= N;++i){
    let soma = 0;
    for(let j = i - 1;j >= 1;--j) 
        soma += i % j!=0 ? 0:j;

    numeros[i] = soma;
    if(soma in numeros && numeros[soma] === i && soma !== i)
        res.push(i,soma);
}
alert(res);
```

Comment: Não entendi porque na versão ilegível `i` começa com 1, mas na legível com 2

Comment: Entendi, o incremento do operador prefixado de `i` está acontecendo simultaneamente com a comparação